# what header file should add for Microsoft.Security

Tags: c#, .net

Hi i am adding this code. throws error in security . how to fix that.

```
int intID = int.Parse(Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["KeyID"]));
```

Comment: C# doesn't have header files.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use [AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com) (which I "own").

However what youy're doing with it doesn't make a great deal of sense, you don't need to HtmlEncode before trying to parse, and, in fact, HtmlEncode would touch integers in query strings, and the encoding method for query strings is (admittedly confusingly) UrlEncde.

Comment: thank you it works . i have installed AntiXSS Library .

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

The [Anti-Cross Site Scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) library, instructions in the link.